A theorem about isotopy similar to Whitney embedding
Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and there are two embeddings $f_0,f_1:M\rightarrow\mathbb R ^{n}$. If $n\ge 2\dim M+3$, then $f_0,f_1$ are isotopic; moreover there is a embedding $F:M\times [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R^{n}$ such that $f_0(x)=F(x,0),f_1(x)=F(x,1)$
How to prove this (even the weaker conclusion that they are isotopic)? It seems that we can apply Whitney embedding theorem in middle, but how to deal with the boundary?

This was proven all the way back in 1936 in Whitney's original paper Differentiable Manifolds, Theorem 6. It is mind-boggling how ahead that paper was. I sadly don't know of a modern reference.
